# Highlight during search not working in vim

Tags: vim

I have in my ~/.vimrc:

```
set hlsearch
```

Indeed, when I start searching for a word such as "dude"

```
/dude
```

the word "dude" highlights nicely as I start typing "dude" after the slash. However, after I hit enter to signify that I am finished typing in my search, the highlighting goes away, and then I cannot see in my script where the word "dude" occurs. When I hit "n" for next, it takes me to the next occurrence of "dude", but again it is not highlighted.

I am on Mac OS in the terminal using vim.

```
:hi Search
```

returns:
    xxx term=reverse ctermbg=11 guibg=Yellow

What can I do to keep highlighting when I search for the word of interest in vim?

Comment: What does `:verbose set hlsearch?` say?

Comment: @glts that does give any output... hmmm

Comment: Type it exactly as shown: `:verbose set hlsearch?`. If there's no output then you haven't `:set hlsearch` in your vimrc.

Comment: @glts it just says "hlsearch" after I type it exactly as shown.

Comment: FWIW, Vim has better tools for *searching* than `/?nN`: `:il dude` or even `:vim dude % | cw`.

Comment: @Cokes: If `:verbose set hlsearch?` just replies with `hlsearch` hlsearch is definitely not set (in your _vimrc). The behavior you describe is exactly the behavior Vim shows if hlsearch is not active. For a quick test: enter `:set hlsearch` manually and try searching again.

Comment: @habi Thanks. I typed :set hlsearch, and I get the same behavior :(

Comment: Hmmm, very strange. Another try: What does `:set highlight?` say? Do you see anywhere in the (long) output the string "l:Search"? If not try `:set highlight+=l:Search`. If there is a "l:n", make a `:set highlight-=l:n`.

Comment: An another try, in the case my previous comment does not help: Maybe your terminal can't show the Search highlighting. Since highlighting of the incremental search seems to work, please make sure that `:hi Search` is set to the same highlighting as `:hi IncSearch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed:

```
hi Search term=reverse cterm=NONE ctermfg=grey ctermbg=blue
```

At first I had cterm=xterm and neglected term=reverse, which somehow led to the behavior above...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the highlighting definitions in your `Search` group aren't recognized / visible, but those of `IncSearch` are. Choose a different colorscheme, fix / override the `Search` definition, or as a quick "don't make me think" fix, mirror the latter to the former via:

```
:hi clear Search
:hi link Search IncSearch
```